# Android Retrofit - wait response finish before onclick method

Tags: android, response, retrofit2

I am getting places with retrofit and google maps api and want to collect them in a list. But this process works asynchronously so my list always returns 0. Is there any way to wait for retrofit response?

I want to use `allItems` list but can't because this issue. If anyone can help, I will be appreciate

Here is my code

My Globals

```
ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean> myList;
ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean> allItems;
```

Button onClick

```
menuOption1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myList = new ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean>();
                allItems = new ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean>();

                    allItems.addAll(selectAll("restaurant", myList));
                    allItems.addAll(selectAll("cafe", myList));
                    allItems.addAll(selectAll("bar", myList));

                // Always return 0
                Log.v("Size", "Places List size : " + allItems.size() + "");
        });
```

selectAll function

```
private ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean> selectAll(final String type, final ArrayList<MapData.ResultsBean> list){

    // Creating an object of our api interface
    ApiService myApi = RetroClient.getApiService();

    // Calling JSON
    Call<MapData> call = myApi.getNearbyPlaces(type, mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mLastLocation.getLongitude(), PROXIMITY_RADIUS);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<MapData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MapData> call, Response<MapData> response) {

            Log.v("Response Code", "Response Code is : " + response.code());

            if (response.isSuccessful()){

                try {

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getResults().size(); i++) {
                        addToList(list, response.body().getResults().get(i));
                    }

                    Log.v(type, "List Size : " + list.size() + "");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something work wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MapData> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    Log.v("Size", "Size of all list : " + list.size() + "");
    return list;

}
```

My Interface

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?sensor=true&key=MY_KEY")
    Call<MapData> getNearbyPlaces(@Query("type") String type, @Query("location") String location, @Query("radius") int radius);

}
```

My MapData Model

```
public class MapData {

    private String next_page_token;
    private String status;
    private List<?> html_attributions;

    private List<ResultsBean> results;

    public String getNext_page_token() {
        return next_page_token;
    }

    public void setNext_page_token(String next_page_token) {
        this.next_page_token = next_page_token;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<?> getHtml_attributions() {
        return html_attributions;
    }

    public void setHtml_attributions(List<?> html_attributions) {
        this.html_attributions = html_attributions;
    }

    public List<ResultsBean> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<ResultsBean> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public static class ResultsBean {
        /**
         * location : {"lat":28.6217885,"lng":77.217058}
         * viewport : {"northeast":{"lat":28.6221309,"lng":77.21731114999999},"southwest":{"lat":28.6207613,"lng":77.21647215000002}}
         */

        private GeometryBean geometry;
        private String icon;
        private String id;
        private String name;
        /**
         * open_now : true
         * weekday_text : []
         */

        private OpeningHoursBean opening_hours;
        private String place_id;
        private double rating;
        private String reference;
        private String scope;
        private String vicinity;
        /**
         * height : 2304
         * html_attributions : ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109950289718771609910/photos\">Rakesh Arora<\/a>"]
         * photo_reference : CoQBdwAAAN7Lk09qvlJpI3LD176UvFqgRK9noYU9zlx0zrOxlBaMzNAeay5pCPlggL-Nd0wVq2hZATJnEL8ZfFdDKRjxOjbH1w04c1EH8t_1iGbyiLj0qurpPb8F6xEyEAT61z37fJzQF5GkS6eZFEIYT0GzFM5bPuFgjSzQJuw6WYmFvk7jEhBzXaMryJPjUO1JtNtdBH2KGhTbSxdPgvE-fnauqam3l0AvFEIusw
         * width : 4096
         */

        private List<PhotosBean> photos;
        private List<String> types;

        public GeometryBean getGeometry() {
            return geometry;
        }

        public void setGeometry(GeometryBean geometry) {
            this.geometry = geometry;
        }

        public String getİcon() {
            return icon;
        }

        public void setİcon(String icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
        }

        public String getİd() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setİd(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public OpeningHoursBean getOpening_hours() {
            return opening_hours;
        }

        public void setOpening_hours(OpeningHoursBean opening_hours) {
            this.opening_hours = opening_hours;
        }

        public String getPlace_id() {
            return place_id;
        }

        public void setPlace_id(String place_id) {
            this.place_id = place_id;
        }

        public double getRating() {
            return rating;
        }

        public void setRating(double rating) {
            this.rating = rating;
        }

        public String getReference() {
            return reference;
        }

        public void setReference(String reference) {
            this.reference = reference;
        }

        public String getScope() {
            return scope;
        }

        public void setScope(String scope) {
            this.scope = scope;
        }

        public String getVicinity() {
            return vicinity;
        }

        public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
            this.vicinity = vicinity;
        }

        public List<PhotosBean> getPhotos() {
            return photos;
        }

        public void setPhotos(List<PhotosBean> photos) {
            this.photos = photos;
        }

        public List<String> getTypes() {
            return types;
        }

        public void setTypes(List<String> types) {
            this.types = types;
        }

        public static class GeometryBean {
            /**
             * lat : 28.6217885
             * lng : 77.217058
             */

            private LocationBean location;
            /**
             * northeast : {"lat":28.6221309,"lng":77.21731114999999}
             * southwest : {"lat":28.6207613,"lng":77.21647215000002}
             */

            private ViewportBean viewport;

            public LocationBean getLocation() {
                return location;
            }

            public void setLocation(LocationBean location) {
                this.location = location;
            }

            public ViewportBean getViewport() {
                return viewport;
            }

            public void setViewport(ViewportBean viewport) {
                this.viewport = viewport;
            }

            public static class LocationBean {
                private double lat;
                private double lng;

                public double getLat() {
                    return lat;
                }

                public void setLat(double lat) {
                    this.lat = lat;
                }

                public double getLng() {
                    return lng;
                }

                public void setLng(double lng) {
                    this.lng = lng;
                }
            }

            public static class ViewportBean {
                /**
                 * lat : 28.6221309
                 * lng : 77.21731114999999
                 */

                private NortheastBean northeast;
                /**
                 * lat : 28.6207613
                 * lng : 77.21647215000002
                 */

                private SouthwestBean southwest;

                public NortheastBean getNortheast() {
                    return northeast;
                }

                public void setNortheast(NortheastBean northeast) {
                    this.northeast = northeast;
                }

                public SouthwestBean getSouthwest() {
                    return southwest;
                }

                public void setSouthwest(SouthwestBean southwest) {
                    this.southwest = southwest;
                }

                public static class NortheastBean {
                    private double lat;
                    private double lng;

                    public double getLat() {
                        return lat;
                    }

                    public void setLat(double lat) {
                        this.lat = lat;
                    }

                    public double getLng() {
                        return lng;
                    }

                    public void setLng(double lng) {
                        this.lng = lng;
                    }
                }

                public static class SouthwestBean {
                    private double lat;
                    private double lng;

                    public double getLat() {
                        return lat;
                    }

                    public void setLat(double lat) {
                        this.lat = lat;
                    }

                    public double getLng() {
                        return lng;
                    }

                    public void setLng(double lng) {
                        this.lng = lng;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static class OpeningHoursBean {
            private boolean open_now;
            private List<?> weekday_text;

            public boolean isOpen_now() {
                return open_now;
            }

            public void setOpen_now(boolean open_now) {
                this.open_now = open_now;
            }

            public List<?> getWeekday_text() {
                return weekday_text;
            }

            public void setWeekday_text(List<?> weekday_text) {
                this.weekday_text = weekday_text;
            }
        }

        public static class PhotosBean {
            private int height;
            private String photo_reference;
            private int width;
            private List<String> html_attributions;

            public int getHeight() {
                return height;
            }

            public void setHeight(int height) {
                this.height = height;
            }

            public String getPhoto_reference() {
                return photo_reference;
            }

            public void setPhoto_reference(String photo_reference) {
                this.photo_reference = photo_reference;
            }

            public int getWidth() {
                return width;
            }

            public void setWidth(int width) {
                this.width = width;
            }

            public List<String> getHtml_attributions() {
                return html_attributions;
            }

            public void setHtml_attributions(List<String> html_attributions) {
                this.html_attributions = html_attributions;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my logchat

```
V/Size: Places List size : 0
V/restaurant: List Size : 20
V/bar: List Size : 21
V/cafe: List Size : 41
```

Comment: Your list is MapData.ResultsBean, but in your Api interface, you used just MapData, i think this is just model not list. Can you share your interface also ? And model class too.

Comment: Check my edited question pls, I also add logchat. There is not any problem about data, it is about asynchronous and synchronously, I need to wait until all data added to list but I can't figure out how can I do that

Comment: Uhm, when you click menuButton, you are adding just new Arraylists. That's why, size is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the list immediately while you are using the asynchronous approach of Retrofit, you will need to wait for the result on the `onResponse` callback.

One way to do this is by using the callback interfaces to report results asynchronously.

```
public interface GetDataCallback {
   void onGetMapData(MapData mapData);
   void onError();
}

private void selectAll(final String type, final GetDataCallback getDataCallback){

    // Creating an object of our api interface
    ApiService myApi = RetroClient.getApiService();

    // Calling JSON
    Call<MapData> call = myApi.getNearbyPlaces(type, mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mLastLocation.getLongitude(), PROXIMITY_RADIUS);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<MapData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MapData> call, Response<MapData> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
               getDataCallback.onGetMapData(response.body());
            } else {
                getDataCallback.onError();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MapData> call, Throwable t) {
           getDataCallback.onError();
        }
    });
}
```

and you can call it as

```
selectAll("restaurant", new GetDataCallback(){
   @Override
   public void onGetMapData(MapData mapData) {
      // Parse your data
   }

   @Override
   public void onError() {
   }
});
```

Comment: Yeah,  but I dont know how should I wait ?

Comment: You are logging outside `onGetMapData`

Comment: I used like this, its okey now, but how can I use myList in a different fuction, in this case "someFunction" ? http://hastebin.com/yodubovabu.java

Comment: You can call it in the last callback, if it needs to be after the third one then you'll have to nest the calls inside each other as you will invoke the second add in the `onGetMapData` of the first one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I made nested calls and it works well :)

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in your onResponse method after `for (;;)`.

```
allItems.addAll(selectAll("restaurant", myList));
                allItems.addAll(selectAll("cafe", myList));
                allItems.addAll(selectAll("bar", myList));
```